# unable to export signed application due to lint warnings

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-lint

I want to export signed application but following Lint error occurs every time to stop me.
How to clear this.
This is google-play-services lint error so I tried 
 Properties -> Android -> Android Lint -> Ignore all.
but no effect..
help me

---

**This is error**

This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)

Issue: Ensures that classes registered in the manifest file are instantiatable
Id: Instantiatable

Activities, services, broadcast receivers etc. registered in the manifest file must be "instantiatable" by the system, which means that the class must be public, it must have an empty public constructor, and if it's an inner class, it must be a static inner class.

[]

Comment: try to clean the project first before exporting the APK

Comment: yes done that. but still not working

Comment: try using using Window -> Preferences ...android lint ignore all

Comment: solved by setting instantiatable as warning of appcompat project

Comment: thanks akshay for sharing this.

Comment: @akshaybhange where to set it?